# CNOT chain vs CNOT fountain in qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, gate-synthesis

I was going through qiskit's synthesis module, their methods take an argument called `cx_structure` which has two possible values, `cnot_chain` & `cnot_fountain`. Their [source code](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/synthesis/evolution/product_formula.html#ProductFormula) has the following examples:

```
"""CX chain.
For example, for the Pauli with the label 'XYZIX'.

                       ┌───┐
        q_0: ──────────┤ X ├
                       └─┬─┘
        q_1: ────────────┼──
                  ┌───┐  │
        q_2: ─────┤ X ├──■──
             ┌───┐└─┬─┘
        q_3: ┤ X ├──■───────
             └─┬─┘
        q_4: ──■────────────
```

and for `cnot_fountain`:

```
"""CX chain in the fountain shape.
For example, for the Pauli with the label 'XYZIX'.

             ┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐
        q_0: ┤ X ├┤ X ├┤ X ├
             └─┬─┘└─┬─┘└─┬─┘
        q_1: ──┼────┼────┼──
               │    │    │
        q_2: ──■────┼────┼──
                    │    │
        q_3: ───────■────┼──
                         │
        q_4: ────────────■──
```

One of the comparison points mentioned was `cnot_chain` reduces the evolution the top qubit has to go through, but apart from that, is there any advantage in terms of circuit depth or any other relevant parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docblock in the mentioned file:

> cx_structure: How to arrange the CX gates for the Pauli evolutions, can be "chain", where next neighbor connections are used, or "fountain", where all qubits are connected to one.

So, if you are targeting a fully connected device (e.g., trapped ion devices),  the value of `cx_structure` will not impact the transpiled circuit depth. On the other hand, if you are targeting a device with constraints on qubit connectivity (e.g., superconducting devices), then setting `cx_structure` value to `chain` should result in a transpiled circuit width smaller depth most of the time.

For example, let's define a one-term hamiltonian:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import Pauli

hamiltonian = Pauli('XYZIZYX')
```

and choose our target to be ibmq_jakarta

```
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider

provider = IBMProvider()
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_jakarta')
```

Now, we compare the depth of the transpiled circuit for both `cx_structure` values:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit.synthesis import SuzukiTrotter
from qiskit.circuit.library import PauliEvolutionGate

for cx_structure in ['chain', 'fountain']:
    evo_time = 1.0
    # Suzuki-Trotter product formula of order 2 and one time step:
    synthesis = SuzukiTrotter(order=2, reps=1, cx_structure=cx_structure)
    gate = PauliEvolutionGate(hamiltonian, evo_time, synthesis=synthesis)

    circ = QuantumCircuit(hamiltonian.num_qubits)
    circ.append(gate, range(hamiltonian.num_qubits))

    trns_circ = transpile(circ, backend=backend, layout_method='sabre', routing_method='sabre')
    print(cx_structure, trns_circ.depth())
```

The output should be something like:

```
chain 21
fountain 32
```

The difference will increase if your Hamiltonian contains many terms, and when you increase number of time steps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [QuantumCircuit.depth](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.depth.html) to detect depth of both?

Comment: So far I haven't encountered any difference, but hey that is not good enough to claim they are the same :)